# How to see resource file content in Visual Studio when created pro programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, localization, resources, culture

I created a resource file programmatically. File got created successfully. But when I tries to open it in Visual Studio or notepad it shows me some encoded characters. I was expecting to get an XML.

Here is what I was expecting and getting.
[image]

What I did in coding is

```
    ResourceWriter rw = new ResourceWriter("Resource.en.resx");
    rw.AddResource(value, "name setter");
  //  rw.AddResource(value, "myname");
    rw.Generate();
    rw.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be using [ResXResourceWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcewriter.aspx) to write resx files.  The ResourceWriter is for writing system-default binary resource files.

Comment: I didn't see that, i was reading many articles that were saying the same but I didn't see at my code about what I am using.